# Unexpected keyword error when trying to upload profile picture in Django

Tags: python, django

I have asked a similar question, but believe I have made quite a lot of changes to my code to warrant asking a new one (also the problem seems to be somewhat different).

I am trying to allow users to upload a profile image but cannot seem to save the image and now getting the error message:

> mentorform = MentorProfileForm(instance=user) TypeError: **init**()
>   got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

This is what I have in views(teachers.py):

```
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    mentorform = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user.mentor)
        if form.is_valid() and mentorform.is_valid():
            m = Mentor.objects.get()
            form.save()
            m.photo = mentorform.cleaned_data['photo']
            m.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('teachers:edit_user')))
        # else:
        #     messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=user)
    context = {'form':form,
               'mentorform':mentorform}
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', context)
```

models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media', default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        post_save.connect(create_or_update, sender=User)
```

forms

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email')

class MentorProfileForm(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.ImageField()
```

and my html form:

```
<form action="{% url upload_pic %}" id="edit-mentor-profile" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media v-middle">
                            <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="icon-block width-100 bg-grey-100">
                                  <img id="image" style="width:99%;height:99%;">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <input type="file" id="files"  name="photo" class="btn btn-white btn-sm paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

This is where the image should appear after it is uploaded and saved:

```
<img src="{{ user.mentor.photo }}" alt="people" class="img-circle width-80" />
```

Comment: Are you wanting `MentorProfileForm` to inherit from `UserForm` so that you can pass it a `User` instance when you initialize the form?

Comment: @ekneiling ideally